# Get the function passed to a eventEmitter Angular 4

Tags: angular, function, typescript, parameters, eventemitter

Is it possible to get the function passed to the Event Emitter?

I have a component and i pass a function to an event emitter like this:

```
<component (onClick)='function(parameter)'></component>
```

and in my Component i have the @Output to recieve the function and to emit when click like this:

```
@Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
<button (click)="onClick.emit($event)">
```

The thing is that i would like to get the function that i pass to the component, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible

Lets say you have a add function inside your child component.

```
  @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
  }
```

And on the buttons click event, you can emit the function

```
 <button (click)="onClick.emit(add)">Add</button>
```

Inside your parent component you can listen on the events from the child component.

```
 <component (onClick)='someFunc($event)'></component>
```

and call the function when the event is triggered.

```
someFunc(add: any) {
  const result = add(5, 5);
  console.log('and result is',result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

`<component (onClick)='function($event)'></component>`

instead of

`<component (onClick)='function(parameter)'></component>`